# How do I debug a websocket server

Tags: websocket

I'm trying to write a server for a webSocket connection. I've read the spec (76, not 75) carefully. I'm using minefield as the browser.

When I try to create a WebSocket from javascript in the browser:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8766/hoho");
```

The browser responds with

"Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8766/hoho."

My server is getting a valid client handshake request, it sends back the response and then boom.

I've run every example handshake example I can find through my server and I match the given responses exactly in every instance. I'm pretty confident that the return byte stream is correct. I don't need help debugging my code, it's doing what I mean it to do. I need help debugging my use of the handshake protocol since when I give minefield what I think is a correct response it laughs at me.

My question is this: How can I debug this thing? I can think of two possibilities.

1. Is there any way to get minefield to tell me WHY it's rejecting my handshake?
2. Is there a working, public, webSocket server service on the web? If there is, I can proxy it, watch the byte streams in both direction and figure out where mine is different.

Does anyone have any ideas in these directions or any other ideas?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [Gimite's Ruby websocket backend](http://github.com/gimite/web-socket-ruby) seems now to support the 76 draft. You could give that a try?

Comment: I also get `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ... ` with "ws://" and `An invalid or illegal string was specified"  code: "12` with "http://".  Chrome gives one better error for this (assuming that it is the same issue) `Wrong url scheme for WebSocket` for "http://", but then a nonsensical one: `Unexpected response code: 200` for "ws://".  The server is generating and sending results.

Comment: I realized that the `Unexpected response code: 200` was actually correct for Google Chrome, that it should be 101.  And the headers I was missing... (http://www.tbray.org/drafts/wsock-00#anchor18)

Answer (score 2):

About the 2nd possibility.
Yes, there is a websocket server out there.
the jWebSocket demo server at http://jwebsocket.org/demos/chat/chat.htm

hope this helps

Added: Echo socket server at: http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the process of debugging a similar situation, and the tool I'm relying on most is netcat, with some additional use of openssl. Shut down your websocket server and run `nc -l 8766`. That lets you record exactly what headers are being sent. Turn the websocket server back on and use `nc 8766` to paste in those same headers and see the result. `openssl s_client -connect localhost:443` will let you make the request with ssl, if that is in your mix.

From there, make sure the responses conform completely to the websocket handshake protocol. For instance, my problem right now is that my responses have `Connection: close`, which is no good.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jsfiddle that I made from http://www.websocket.org echo websocket server which works in Chrome but not in Firefox 6: http://jsfiddle.net/awDLc/

It is adjusted to use MozWebSocket rather than WebSocket, but perhaps that isn't enough?